# How to write mobx action methods in separate files and import them to the actual mobx class having observable variables?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I have a mobx class which has an observable variable named dataObject. This observable variable is an object and its structure is:

```
{
   name:string;
   dataType:string;
   value: string;
   description:string;
   .
   .
   .
   .
   . 
   ..... total around 45 such properties
}
```

Each object property has an action method to update it. For example

```
@action updateName = (name:string) =>{
   this.dataObject.name = name;
}
```

It is difficult to maintain all such 45 action methods in same class. Is there any way to write these methods in a separate ts file and import them to the current file?

EDIT: Adding a part of dataObject interface along with few of its action methods

```
interface IDataObject{
    name:string;
    dataType:string;
    value:any;
    valueType:VALUE_TYPE|any;
    hasCustomValueType:boolean;
    customValueType:string|undefined;
    description:string;
    isRegistered:boolean;
    associatedVariableDetails:IVariableDetails[];
    hasMultipleValues:boolean;
    associatedService:SERVICE;
}

enum VALUE_TYPE{
    MAJOR = 'major',
    MED = 'med',
    MINOR = 'minor'
}

enum SERVICE{
    PUSH_IN = 'pushin',
    PULL_OUT = 'pullout'
}

interface IVariableDetails{
    variableName:string;
    varirbleDataType:string;
    variableValue:any;
    hasArray:boolean;
    isDeletable:boolean;    
}

//////////////
method to update dataType
@action updateDataType = (dataType:string) =>{
    this.dataObject.dataType = dataType;
    if(dataType === 'string'){
        this.dataObject.value = ''
    }
    else if(dataType === 'boolean'){
        this.dataObject.value = false
    }
    else if(dataType === 'integer'){
        this.dataObject.value = 0
    }
}


methods to modify associatedVariableDetails

@action addVariableDetails = (variableDetails:IVariableDetails) =>{
    this.dataObject.associatedVariableDetails.push(variableDetails);
}

@action updateMultipleValueState = (hasMultipleValues:boolean) =>{
    this.dataObject.hasMultipleValues = hasMultipleValues;
    if(!hasMultipleValues){
        this.dataObject.associatedVariableDetails = this.dataObject.associatedVariableDetails[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface for the object that you want as the observable and add an index signature.

This looks something like this:

```
interface foo {
  [key: string]: type;
  bar: string;
}
```

Then pass the key to your update action and update the value like `object[key] = newValue`.

Example:

```
    @action update = (key: string, value: type) => {
      object[key] = value;
    }
```

This will allow you to use one single function to patch any value into your observable object.

This is a good article that explains index signatures in depth: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html

To answer your original question though. You could create 45 functions and export all of them in an object and import them into this file, but that solution may be overkill and tedious to maintain if types or fields change. I can show an example of that if this solution does not work. The solution I have explained above is the more efficient way of handling object patches.

EDIT:

I apologize for the delay in editing my answer. I have made edits to your code above showing the approach I would be taking with this kind of object you have. Here is the edit:

```
interface IDataObject{
    [key: string]: string | boolean | VALUE_TYPE | SERVICE | IVariableDetails[];
    name: string;
    dataType: string;
    value: any; // THIS SHOULD BE STRICTLY DEFINED
    valueType: VALUE_TYPE|any; // THIS SHOULD ALSO BE STRICTLY DEFINED
    hasCustomValueType: boolean;
    customValueType?: string;
    description: string;
    isRegistered:boolean;
    associatedVariableDetails: IVariableDetails[];
    hasMultipleValues: boolean;
    associatedService: SERVICE;
}

enum VALUE_TYPE{
    MAJOR = 'major',
    MED = 'med',
    MINOR = 'minor'
}

enum SERVICE{
    PUSH_IN = 'pushin',
    PULL_OUT = 'pullout'
}

interface IVariableDetails{
    variableName:string;
    varirbleDataType:string;
    variableValue:any;
    hasArray:boolean;
    isDeletable:boolean;    
}

@action updateField = (key: string, value: string | boolean | VALUE_TYPE | SERVICE) => {
    this.dataObject[key] = value;
}
@action addVariableDetails = (variableDetails: IVariableDetails) => {
    this.dataObject.associatedVariableDetails.push(variableDetails);
}
@action updateMultipleValueState = (hasMultipleValues: boolean) => {
    this.dataObject.hasMultipleValues = hasMultipleValues;
    if(!hasMultipleValues){
        this.dataObject.associatedVariableDetails = this.dataObject.associatedVariableDetails[0];
    }
}
```

What I have done here is exposed a single method to manipulate the semi primitive values that do not need extra work after, they just want new values. Then I would create more complex `@actions` as needed based on the type of work you need to do on your object. As shown the `updateField` action does not allow you to use it with a `VariableDetails` type of parameter which will make it so typescript complains if you try to send a variableDetails parameter to that action.

I have also noted that the `any` attributes should definitely be some type if the rest of the object has strict typings. If you are going to have `any` types in your object you might as well make an interface like `interface IAny { [key: string]: any; }` and use that everywhere.

I hope this can be of help, and again I apologize for the gap in responses.

Comment: Actually there has to be separate 45 functions. The dataObject has not only single level properties like name, description etc but also has nested objects as property. Also each method's implementation varies according to the type of action I'm performing. For example, on @action updateDataType, the value needs to be reset along with setting of dataType

Comment: Can you possibly show an example of your complete object and an update operation you intend on making?